# Terraform AWS Dashboard - Widgets from nested list

Tags: terraform, dashboard, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform beginner here. I am trying to create some widgets from a nested list. Group will be a "label" widget indicating the group followed by the metric widgets for the canaries related to the group. So the dashboard should look as follows:

Group 1
widget1, widget2 etc.
Group 2
widget3, widget4 etc.

Variable value:

```
dashboard = [
    {
        name = "Group-1",
        canaries  = ["canary1", "canary2", "canary3"]
    },
    {
        name = "Group-2",
        canaries  = ["canary4", "canary5"]
    }
]
```

Attempt at building json:

```
locals {
    body = [for group in var.dashboard :
                #Create text widget for Group name
                {
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 24,
                    "y": 4,
                    "x": 0,
                    "type": "text",
                    "properties": {
                        "markdown": "\n#  > [${group.name}]\n"
                    }
                }
                #Attempt to create underlying widgets for group
                [for canary in group.canaries :
                    {
                        {
                            "height": 3,
                            "width": 6,
                            "y": 5,
                            "x": 0,
                            "type": "metric",
                            "properties": {
                                "metrics": [
                                    [ "CloudWatchSynthetics", "Failed", "CanaryName", "${canary}", { "label": "Canary failures count", "region": "us-west-2" } ]
                                ],
                                "title": "Failed canary runs",
                                "period": 60,
                                "region": "us-west-2",
                                "stat": "Sum",
                                "view": "singleValue",
                                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ] #TF Doesn't like the inclusion of nested loop here or my syntax is incorrect.
            ]
}
```

Resource creation:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "canary_dashboard" {
    dashboard_name = "Canary-Dashboard"
    dashboard_body = jsonencode({
        "widgets": concat(local.body)
    })
}
```

In my creation of `body`, Terraform complains about `Missing close bracket on index`, but I have triple checked that I am not missing a bracket or curly brace. How do I dynamically create the dashboard widgets from nested lists?

**Edit**
Including desired json output below as suggested by Jordan. In the end, there will be `n` number of groups, each having `n` number of canaries belonging to said group.

```
{
    "widgets": [
        {
            "height": 1,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 4,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "text",
            "properties": {
                "markdown": "\n# Group1\n"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 3,
            "width": 6,
            "y": 5,
            "x": 6,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "CloudWatchSynthetics", "Failed", "CanaryName", "Group1-Canary", { "label": "Canary failures count", "region": "us-west-2" } ]
                ],
                "title": "Failed canary runs",
                "period": 60,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "stat": "Sum",
                "view": "singleValue",
                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 1,
            "width": 24,
            "y": 4,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "text",
            "properties": {
                "markdown": "\n# Group2\n"
            }
        },
        {
            "height": 3,
            "width": 6,
            "y": 5,
            "x": 6,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "CloudWatchSynthetics", "Failed", "CanaryName", "Group2-Canary", { "label": "Canary failures count", "region": "us-west-2" } ]
                ],
                "title": "Failed canary runs",
                "period": 60,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "stat": "Sum",
                "view": "singleValue",
                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do something with list comprehension that Terraform doesn't allow (see where I've marked "HERE"):

```
locals {
    body = [for group in var.dashboard :
                #Create text widget for Group name
                {
                    "height": 1,
                    "width": 24,
                    "y": 4,
                    "x": 0,
                    "type": "text",
                    "properties": {
                        "markdown": "\n#  > [${group.name}]\n"
                    }
                }                                                       <===== HERE
                #Attempt to create underlying widgets for group
                [for canary in group.canaries :
                    {
                        {
                            "height": 3,
                            "width": 6,
                            "y": 5,
                            "x": 0,
                            "type": "metric",
                            "properties": {
                                "metrics": [
                                    [ "CloudWatchSynthetics", "Failed", "CanaryName", "${canary}", { "label": "Canary failures count", "region": "us-west-2" } ]
                                ],
                                "title": "Failed canary runs",
                                "period": 60,
                                "region": "us-west-2",
                                "stat": "Sum",
                                "view": "singleValue",
                                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ] #TF Doesn't like the inclusion of nested loop here or my syntax is incorrect.
            ]
}
```

If TF allowed you to do what you're trying to do, you'd end up with something like:

```
body = [
  {
    "height": 1,
    "width": 24,
    "y": 4,
    "x": 0,
    "type": "text",
    "properties": {
      "markdown": "\n#  > [${group.name}]\n"
    }
  },
  [
    {
        {
            "height": 3,
            "width": 6,
            "y": 5,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "CloudWatchSynthetics", "Failed", "CanaryName", "${canary}", { "label": "Canary failures count", "region": "us-west-2" } ]
                ],
                "title": "Failed canary runs",
                "period": 60,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "stat": "Sum",
                "view": "singleValue",
                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        {
            "height": 3,
            "width": 6,
            "y": 5,
            "x": 0,
            "type": "metric",
            "properties": {
                "metrics": [
                    [ "CloudWatchSynthetics", "Failed", "CanaryName", "${canary}", { "label": "Canary failures count", "region": "us-west-2" } ]
                ],
                "title": "Failed canary runs",
                "period": 60,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "stat": "Sum",
                "view": "singleValue",
                "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
            }
        }
    }
  ]
]
```

And I doubt that's what you're trying to do. If you can provide a sample of what you'd like the JSON to look like, we can show you how to achieve it.